# Open an ssh session in a particular directory on openshift with a prompt

Tags: ssh, openshift

I want to open an ssh session in particular directory on openshift. If I type

```
rhc ssh myapp  "cd app-root/repo ; bash"
```

it does open a session in that particular directory, and I can type commands, but there is no command prompt. If I just type

```
rhc ssh myapp
```

I do get the command prompt.  How do I get the command prompt back when I add the `cd app-root/repo ; bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-t` switch to force TTY allocation on the server:

```
rhc ssh --ssh "ssh -tt" myapp  "cd app-root/repo ; bash"
```

should do the job.

Comment: This generates and error to the effect that the  ```-t``` option is ambiguous. If I use ```rhc ssh --help``` , the options starting with t are ```timeout``` and ```token```.

Comment: Give it a try with `--ssh "ssh -tt"` (modified the answer).